# Unable to use proxies with twitter api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twitter, proxy

I'm using sferik's gem which works great, except when I try using with a proxy. (https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Configuration.md#using-a-proxy)

That's the code I have:

```
proxy = nil
if account.proxy_ip.present?
  proxy = {
      host: account.proxy_ip,
      port: account.proxy_port
  }
  proxy[:username] = account.proxy_user
  proxy[:password] = account.proxy_password
end
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = account.consumer_key
  config.consumer_secret     = account.consumer_secret
  config.access_token        = account.access_token_key
  config.access_token_secret = account.access_token_secret
  config.proxy               = proxy if proxy.present?
end
client.update('hello world')
```

And that's the error I get:

```
undefined method `host=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:31:in `block in update'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:20:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:20:in `update'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:7:in `from'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:231:in `from'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:286:in `proxy'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:83:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:70:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:70:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:97:in `connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/rest/request.rb:25:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:50:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:50:in `perform_request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:95:in `perform_request_with_objects'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:87:in `perform_post_with_objects'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/rest/users.rb:232:in `block in users'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/utils.rb:37:in `block in pmap'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/utils.rb:37:in `each_slice'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/utils.rb:37:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/utils.rb:37:in `collect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/utils.rb:37:in `pmap'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/utils.rb:25:in `flat_pmap'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/rest/users.rb:231:in `users'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/rest/friends_and_followers.rb:112:in `block in follow'
```

The proxy ip and port are set correctly. I'm unable to figure out what's the problem. Any clue how to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I digged into [faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday)'s connection library, which is used by the [twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem to establish the connection to the API. Turns out that the proxy hash isn't expecting neither a `host` or a `port` attribute. Instead, it takes an `uri` attribute that must be an instance of `Addressable::URI` ([Check out the code here](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/connection.rb))

So, if you are using the `Twitter::REST::Client` behind a proxy, here is how you must declare it :

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new({
  consumer_key: "consumer_key",
  consumer_secret: "consumer_secret",
  access_token: "access_token_key",
  access_token_secret: "access_token_secret",
  proxy: {
    uri: Addressable::URI.parse("http://proxy_host:proxy_port"),
    username: "proxy_username",
    password: "proxy_password"
  }
})
```

Hope this helps. Cheers !